# xamarin How to Hot Update Mono.Android?

Tags: xamarin

The system loads the mono after the link is removed by default, and some code is currently reloaded. Using Assembly.load returns the default and cannot be updated
By byte [] load two mono references will appear but the application cannot find new references

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `Target Framework` to update the Mono.Android version.

[image]